# You currently can't modify MaintenanceWindow with Aurora Serverless - error while updating Cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I Have a parameter `PreferredMaintenanceWindow` setup within `AWS::RDS::DBCluster` in my cloudformation template and it was all good. 
Recently I had to add the parameter `EnableCloudwatchLogsExport` to the template, but when I tried to deploy the stack it failed with the following message:

> You currently can't modify MaintenanceWindow with Aurora Serverless.
>   (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>   InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID:
>   bf40fd7e-e599-481a-ac23-b3c68e9794a1)

This is when I didn't even touch that parameter, did anyone faced such issue or any workaround which I can use with CloudFormation

PS: I am aware that I can setup the `EnableCloudwatchLogsExport` from the CLI but I don't want drift and I would really want it to do it via cloudformatio.

Update:

```
RDSServerlessDB:
    Type: "AWS::RDS::DBCluster"
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZones:
        Fn::GetAZs: !Ref 'AWS::Region'
      BackupRetentionPeriod: 3                                                # Number of days
      DatabaseName: !Join ["_", [!Join ["_", !Split [ "-", !Sub '${MasterStack}']], 'fol']]
      DBClusterParameterGroupName: "default.aurora5.6"
      DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref RDSDBSubnetGroup
      EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
        - error
        - general
        - slowquery
        - audit
      Engine: "aurora"
      EngineMode: "serverless" 
      #      EngineVersion: "5.6.10a"
      MasterUsername: "username"                                            
      MasterUserPassword: "{{resolve:ssm-secure:/password:1}}"
#      Port: 3306
#      PreferredMaintenanceWindow: "sun:01:00-sun:03:00"
      ScalingConfiguration:
        AutoPause: True
        MaxCapacity: 32
        MinCapacity: 2
        SecondsUntilAutoPause: 300
      Tags:
        - Key: owner
          Value: !Ref StackOwner
        - Key: task
          Value: !Ref Task
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - Ref: RDSSecurityGroup
```

Comment: Can you upload or link your template?


[AWS::RDS::DBCluster docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html)

Comment: @PatMyron I have updated my question with the RDS template. I figured if I comment out Port, PreferredMaintenanceWindow then the stack update works normally. Seems like its a cloudformation bug.

Comment: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/396

Comment: Same error when updating via AWS CLI as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/396).

As a work-around, you can temporarily remove (or comment out) `PreferredBackupWindow` and `PreferredMaintenanceWindow` from the template. In my testing, the CF update succeeds and both values are left intact on the instance configuration.

There is actually some debate as to what the expected behavior is. The bug report comments say these settings are not supported in *serverless* mode, but the AWS Documentation and AWS Console don't seem to support that assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a limitation (among many others) of Aurora Serverless v1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.limitations (it's the last in the list of limitations).

I tried setting it with the AWS CLI v1 and with the AWS Java SDK v2:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.rds.model.ScalingConfiguration scalingConfiguration = software.amazon.awssdk.services.rds.model.ScalingConfiguration.builder().minCapacity(1).build()
final ModifyDbClusterRequest request = ModifyDbClusterRequest.builder().dbClusterIdentifier(clusterIdentifier).preferredBackupWindow("18:00-19:00").scalingConfiguration(scalingConfiguration).build()
final ModifyDbClusterResponse response = rdsClient.modifyDBCluster(request)
```

It returns the same error regardless.